# Restore SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server

I'm attempting to restore a SQL Server database that was on one server to a new server via SSMS. I right-click on `Databases` and select `Restore Database...`.

From the `Restore Database` window, I select the `Device` radio button and add my `.bak` file to the Backup media list using the "Add" button. If I click the "Contents" button, everything looks great. The contents window shows all the info about the back such as the database name, the fact it was a full backup, the server name it was backed up from, username, etc...  So, I know the backup file is valid.

However, when I return to the Restore Database screen from the Select Backup Device window, nothing shows in the "Backup sets to restore:" grid and the OK button is disabled. So, I'm not able to restore the backup.

I'm not sure what version of SQL Server I'm coming from but the destination version is 11.0.6579.0

Comment: What if you try a T-SQL Restore? Something like `restore [database_name] from disk = 'path_to_file;`?

Comment: I will give that a try. Thanks for your reply.